# Ember Data: Prevent encodeURIComponent on Query Params

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am working with an API which requires the use of reserved words, against [the recommendation of the specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).  I need to override the default behaviour of encoding the URL.

Here are my query params:

```
export default Ember.Mixin.create({
    keywords: null,
    genre: Ember.computed.alias("applicationController.genre"),
    qualities: ["720p", "1080p", "3d"],
    quality: "720p,1080p,3d",
    queryParams: ["keywords", "page", "perPage", "genre", "sort", "quality"],
    perPage: 50,
    page: 1,
    sort: "asc"
});
```

Currently, the request goes out with `,` characters replaced with `%2c`.  How can I keep my query param value for `quality`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override `ajaxOptions` on your adapter.
The default implementation gives the `.data` directly to jQuery, and jQuery is doing the encoding of the query params then. Maybe somethis like this could do the job:

```
ajaxOptions() {
  let hash = this._super(...arguments);

  if(hash.data && hash.type === 'GET') {
    hash.url += '?' + Object.keys(hash.data).map(key => {
        return `${key}=${hash.data[key]}`;
    }).join('&');
    delete hash.data;
  }

  return hash;
}
```